# chrome extension code to get current active tab url and detect any url update in it as well

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to write a chrome extension which can get the URL of active tab. I want it to always display the current website the person is viewing on his active tab of the current active window. I use the following code in my background script:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener( function(activeInfo){
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab){
        y = tab.url;
        console.log("you are here: "+y);
    });
});
```

This code displays current urls fine whenever I change the active tab in browser. But If I change the active tab url manually by clicking or typing, it fails to register the new url and will only do so if we switch between tabs and come back to this tab. I want to detect both the cases. How should I change my code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Below is a script which takes care of both the cases:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener( function(activeInfo){
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab){
        y = tab.url;
        console.log("you are here: "+y);
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, change, tab) => {
    if (tab.active && change.url) {
        console.log("you are here: "+change.url);           
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the manifest? No errors, but do not work for me

Answer (score 2):

you should use the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` api

```
const getActiveUrl = (tabid, changeInfo, tab) => {
  const url = changeInfo.url;

  // url is likely to be empty, and filter chrome:// and about:// URLs
  if (!url || ['chrome://', 'about://'].some(p => url.startsWith(p))) return;

  // filtering is not an active tab
  if (!tab.active) return;

  // the url address you need
  console.log(url);
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(getActiveUrl);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (!tab.active) return;` ?

Comment: yep, i didn't notice this error, thank you very much for correcting me, I have fixed this problem.

Comment: What is the manifest? No errors, but do not work for me